# Odds on rolling a rhombicosidodecahedron

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, recreational-mathematics

This is more of a curiosity to me, but I'm sure I don't have the mathematical skills to answer it.  That said... I took a look at several other posts with questions that relate to this one, but I haven't seen this specifically addressed...

Given a uniform solid [rhombicosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron), what are the odds of rolling each of the faces: triangle, square and pentagon?

I'm interested in a theoretical answer here, I'm not concerned with reality... like a roller trying to "cheat" the roll for a specific outcome.  And I'm obviously not concerned with the die being "fair".  So let's assume that the roll is truly random.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46684/fair-but-irregular-polyhedral-dice

Comment: This can be calculated by finding the solid angles, e.g. with the tetrahedral formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron, using the Cartesian coordinates in the article linked in the question.

Comment: I am doubtful that simple geometry will resolve this issue; here is an [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3925) from the physics literature that addresses some of the complicating factors.

Comment: The spherical approximation should do for “a theoretical answer” or for the limit of a die thrown high above an adhesive surface.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "spherical approximation".  But I'll take a stab at it.... If I take the orthographic projection and measure the surface area for each face type, the ratios there would give the answer?  If so, would that not be the same as the ratio of their areas without the projection?

Comment: I agree with Carlo Beenakker; it is unclear what is meant by a "theoretical answer." As soon as you talk about "rolling," you must at minimum bring physics into the picture, and then lots of complicated considerations immediately arise. See for example this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234029725_The_three-dimensional_dynamics_of_the_die_throw

Comment: @MattF. : Your "spherical approximation" sounds like Simpson's model, which, as the paper cited by Carlo Beenakker explains in detail, is a poor fit to experimental data. It might be okay for an "adhesive surface" if by that you mean a surface that brings the die's motion to an abrupt halt the instant it first touches the surface, but this is not what most people think of as "rolling" a die.

Comment: "Theoretical answer", I'll try to explain.  For example, on a 6-sided die (d6), the theoretical odds for each side are 1 in 6.  That can be effected by people weighting the die, or rolling in a certain manner, or even by the die having some edges slightly scuffed, etc.  I'm not concerned about any of those factors.  So, if I had asked the question about a d6, I would be expcting the answer of 1 in 6 for each side.

Comment: @TimothyChow, it's a poor fit for an oblong solid, but this solid is close to spherical.

Comment: See [Bill Thurston's musings](https://mathoverflow.net/a/49480/6094) in the posting to which Carlo linked. E.g., "If the projected image of a die along a certain axis is almost round, then at low energy levels it should roll more easily about those axes than about axes where the projection is bumpy, other things being equal. This suggests larger components of the phase space for these kinds of rolls, when the phase space becomes disconnected."

Comment: Note circumradius/inradius = 1.05 for this solid (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmallRhombicosidodecahedron.html) vs 2.55 for the die in the linked arxiv article

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a first pass, we can approximate the odds of landing on a face by projecting the polyhedron on a sphere, and taking the fraction of the sphere which it covers.

[image: polyhedron][image: projection]

Then the odds of a triangular, square or pentagonal roll overall are
$$14.4\%,\ 50.4\%,\ 35.1\%$$
and the odds for an individual triangular, square or pentagonal face are
$$0.72\%,\ 1.68\%,\ 2.93\%.$$

This is Simpson's method.  It also represents the result of throwing the die high above an adhesive surface, so that the die is well-randomized in the air, and then after touching the surface falls onto the nearest side.

The angles have exact formulas which are easy enough to calculate in Mathematica:

```
data = PolyhedronData["SmallRhombicosidodecahedron"];
faces = Map[data[[1, 1]][[#]] &, data[[1, 2, 1]]];
angle[a_, b_, c_] := 2 ArcTan[Abs[a.Cross[b, c]]/
     (Norm[a] Norm[b] Norm[c] + a.b Norm[c] + b.c Norm[a] + c.a Norm[b])];
Map[Length[#] angle[# // Mean // Simplify, #[[1]], #[[2]]] &, faces]
     // FullSimplify // Union
```

This gives the following solid angle measures for each triangular, square or pentagonal face:
$$6 \cot^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{3} u+\sqrt{124 u-61}\right),\\
8 \cot^{-1}\left(2u+\sqrt{40 u-21}\right),\\
10 \cot^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{5u}+3 \sqrt{2u+1}\right)$$
where $u=5+2\sqrt{5}$.