# Is there more than one pseudo-Catalan solid?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, recreational-mathematics

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441955/list-of-pseudo-catalan-solids) question was asked on MSE a year ago. Motivation for this question can be found in other MSE questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620288/is-this-solid-gyrate-deltoidal-icositetrahedron-a-fair-die), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156614/is-this-shape-a-fair-d-24) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46684/fair-but-irregular-polyhedral-dice).

Convex solids can have all sorts of symmetries:

- the platonic solids are vertex and face-transitive, meaning there is a subgroup of the rotations of 3-dimensional space which can bring any vertex onto another one (and the same for faces). The list there is limited to the 5 platonic solids.
- face transitive (or isohedral) solids include the Catalan solids, the (infinite family) of dipyramids and the (infinite family) of trapezohedra. Note that without further restricitions these solids can come in infinite families: the rhombic dodecahedron has an infinite number of deltoidal cousins (see [deltoidal dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedron#Deltoidal_dodecahedron)); it also fits in a one-parameter family of dodecahedra called [pyritohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Pyritohedron); the dodecahedron and the triakis tetrahedron fit in the one-parameter family called [tetartoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron#Tetartoid); dipyramids and trapezohedron also admit all sorts of deformations beside the number of faces.
- there is a much weaker symmetry one can ask for. Let's call it pseudo-Catalan (for lack of a better name). Fix a "centre" $C$. The convex solid is pseudo-Catalan, if each face can be sent to another face by a rotation with centre $C$ or a reflection (whose plane goes through $C$). Note that there is no requirement that this rotation (+ reflection) preserve the whole solid. An example of such a solid which is *not* a Catalan solid is the [gyrate deltoidal icositetrahedron](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GyrateDeltoidalIcositetrahedron.html).

**Question:** is there a list of solids which are pseudo-Catalan but not Catalan? [More desperately: is there any such solid beside the gyrate deltoidal icositetrahedron?]

- note that there would be a last category, where the solid is convex and all the faces are congruent (a convex monohedral solid). The difference with the previous category is that translations are now allowed. In particular, to check that a solid belongs to the previous category, the choice of $C$ (and the fact that all rotations and reflections are constrained by this point) is important. Examples of such solids are the the [triaugmented triangular prism](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/TriaugmentedTriangularPrism.html) and the [gyroelongated square dipyramid](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/GyroelongatedSquareDipyramid.html).

Comment: For pseudo-Catalan, do you really mean that every face can be sent to just *another* face, or to *each* other face?

Comment: @M.Winter Well... I thought of it this way: 1- start with one (and only one) face. 2- Then you send this face to every other face using the allowed symmetry group $G$ (i.e. the group of rotations with center $C$ and reflections which fix $C$). Since the operation are invertible, it means: every face can be sent to another face using $G$. However, it is not required that the symmetries preserve the solid. So if the face $F$ is sent to the face $F'=gF$ using $g \in G$, it might be that there is another face $X$ so that $gX$ is not a face of the solid.

Comment: I have the feeling that [this older question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362080/108884) asks something very similar. In particular, an answer links to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/146763/108884) which depicts a polyhedron that might fit your conditions. Does it?

Comment: @M.Winter (1) a positive answer to this question is definitively a answer to yours but I'm not sure the converse holds (if there is an example where the insphere touches the faces at a different point, then the converse is false) (2) the antiprism with pyramids glued on top seems promising (need to check it out)...

Comment: @M.Winter So... I finally got the time to check. When looking at these "biaugmented antiprisms" I started with two parameters. One of them is actually fixed as a function of the other in order for the faces to be congruent. The other is then determined when you require the faces to have fixed distance from the centre. It just turns out the point of least distance is always the circumcentre of the triangular faces. So this fits for my list. Thanks! [I actually only did this numerically for the 12, 16 and 20 faces polyhedron]

Comment: On the down side: it does not help to see if solids which answer your question automatically answer mine. Also I would [naively] expect to find much more solids (in either list)...

Comment: A user over at MSE pointed out that the first item on the list is incorrectly stated. Face- and vertex-transitive solids contain the platonic solids, but there are also other solids (like the disphenoid) which are in this category.

Comment: You might find [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376071/what-are-the-known-convex-polyhedra-with-congruent-faces) useful in your search; it's a necessary but not sufficient condition for what you're looking for, but still restricted enough that it seems like the set of known examples is quite small.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect thanks for the links! indeed, apart from the two below, there does not seem to be any other ones which answer this question. Except perhaps if on of those "twisted gyroelongated dipyramids" could also be made so as to have an insphere (for some $k$).

Answer (score 4):

This is just a detailed version of the comments.

As M. Winter [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146763/can-the-sphere-be-partitioned-into-small-congruent-cells) there is a family of polyhedra with $4k$-faces which fit the bill ($k=5$ is the icosahedra). Here is an image for the case $k=4$ and $k=6$.

[image]
[image]

Start with an antiprism over a $k$-gon (say the lower $k$-gon has vertices with coordinate $(e^{i \pi (2j+1)k},0)$ and the upper vertices $(e^{i \pi 2j k},h)$ where $0 \leq j <k$ and $h$ is a real number; I'm using complex numbers for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates).
Glue a pyramid on each $k$-gon (the tip of the pyramids are at $(0,0,s)$ and $(0,0,h -s)$.
The centre $C$ is at $(0,0,\tfrac{h}{2})$.

For the triangles to be congruent one can write $h$ as a function of $s$ (it's $h = \tfrac{ 2\cos(\pi/k)-1+s^2}{2s}$).
If $k>3$, requiring each face to be at the same distance from $C$ (i.e. $C$ will be the centre of an insphere) will fix a value of $s$ (it's $=\sqrt{2\cos(\pi/k)+1}$).
The point of the faces which minimises the distance to $C$ are [rather, seem to be] the circumcenter of the triangles (only checked this for $k=4,6$ and $7$ [I was too lazy to do the algebra for general $k$]).

From there it follows that these solids are pseudo-Catalan (they cannot be Catalan [if $k \neq 5$] since the vertices at the tip of the pyramids have degree $k$ while the other vertices have degree 5. Hence there is no global symmetry which sends a face from the pyramids to the antiprism.

I would tend to believe that these solids are in a larger family with scalene triangles.
A similar construct based on trapezohedra (instead of dipyramids) would be fun (but I have no idea how to do this at the moment).

EDIT: the case $k=3$ is singular: if you force the planes of the faces to touch the insphere, you get a trapezohedron (whose faces are rhombi; i.e. the triangles of the pyramid align perfectly with those of the antiprism). If you further use the remaining parameter so that the closest point to $C$ is the same on each [triangular] face, it actually gives the cube (!).

Comment: I called these solids "biaugmented antiprisms", but then noticed they could also be called  "gyroelongated dipyramids". Note that the Johnson solid called "gyroelongated square dipyramid" is essentially identical to the solid $k=4$ above, but because its faces are equilateral triangles, it does not have an insphere.

Comment: It turns out that the "biaugmented antiprisms"/"gyroelongated dipyramids" are described combinatorially in a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00373-021-02314-9) by David Eppstein (also on the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00116)) and attributed to Michael Goldberg. Although I did not find the mention that there is a member in those families which have an insphere touching the faces at the same point. The "gyrate dipyramid" in the other answer are also in D.Eppstein's paper and are called "biarc hull" there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (and hopefully simpler) example (though definitively not a complete list of possible solids).
Take a $k$-dipyramid (the equatorial vertices have $xy$-coordinate which are $k^\text{th}$-roots of unity and $z=0$).
Let the tips of the pyramids be at $(0,0,\pm 1)$.
When $k$ is even (so $k \geq 4$), one can cut this pyramid along the plane which goes through the tips and the roots of unity $\pm 1$.
This cuts the dipyramid along a square.
Now rotate one of the two pieces by 90° and paste them back together.
The resulting solids (which should, I assume, be called gyrate dipyramids) satisfy the required conditions.

To see that these are not Catalan solids (unless $k=4$, which is just taking the octaeder, cutting it and putting it back together) just observe that there are two types of faces: those which touch the square where the glueing occurred and the others.

Here are some pictures for $k=6$ and $k=8$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it somehow clear that each face can be brought onto every other face by a rotation or reflection?

Comment: I thought of it so: the statement holds for the original solid (dipyramid) w.r.t to the center $C$ (which is the origin in my coordinates). Since the gyrate dipyramid is obtained from the dipyramid by applying a rotation (which belongs to the allowed rotation group) to a part of its faces, the statement follows for the dipyramid too.

Comment: In other words, assume $f_1$ and $f_2$ are faces of the gyrate dipyramid (and $f_i'$ are the corresponding face of the dipyramid), then either (1) both $f_i$ belong to the same piece [the rotated or unrotated one] or (2) they don't. If (1) then there is a rotation (because that's the case for the dipyramid). If (2): (a) WLOG $f_2$ belongs to the rotated piece (b) let $\rho$ denote the rotation by 90° (which was performed on only one piece) and $\phi$ be the rotation which brings $f_1'$ to $f_2'$ (c) then $\rho \phi$ brings $f_1$ to $f_2$ (since $\rho$ brings $f_2'$ to $f_2$).

Comment: I agree, quite obvious when you explain it that way :D I wonder: is there a reason why you exclude e.g. rotoreflections mapping one face to another? I would have expected that you are okay with any kind of congruence between the faces as long as they fix the origin.

Comment: hmm... actually I'm essentially fine with any isometry fixing $C$. I thought rotoreflections were a composition of a rotation and a reflection? But maybe the problem is my formulation in the question ... so I actually meant each face can be sent to another by any element of the group generated by rotations (with center $C$) and reflections (which fix $C$); i.e. the group of isometries fixing $C$.